# offsite dvd storage

Tags: backup

Is there an offsite service i can use where a 3rd party will keep my dvds for me?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

For backup storage, a [safe deposit box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_deposit_box) at your local bank is always a good option.  An added benefit is being able to store personal files and valuables.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution is the best. :)

Answer (score 2):

Encrypt your backups!

Now any closet/garage is a 'secure off site location'

If this is for a work setting, this could be pretty fun. Just mail the monthly (encrypted) backups to your bosses house.

```
Dear Mr CEO,

I am this months backup dvd's.
Please place me in the box in your garage with all the other dvd's.
But remember, I am the sum total of your digital assets - I am worth 
<insert large million dollar figure here>.

   So look after me.
   Regards - dvd #1232
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you live, [Iron Mountain](http://www.ironmountain.com/index.asp) provides secure offsite storage, recovery, couriering, logging and delivery, as well as a bunch of other services in this realm -- from paper shredding to online backup.  No I don't work for them, and have no vested interest to disclose.